# merging rows based on common id in first column by adding those value?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a tab-delimited file:

```
    Class      Sample_1     Sample_2      Sample_3
    A          0            0             0
    Z          0.25         0             0.75
    A|B|C      0            0             0
    A|B|C      0            1             0
    A|B|C      0.1875       0.671875      0.140625
    A|B|C      0.2739726027 0.5890410959  0.1369863014
    A|B|C|D|E  0            0.2           0.8
    A|B|C|D    0.1666666667 0.3333333333  0.5
    A|B|C|D    0.4723756906 0.179558011   0.3480662983
```

I want to merge the rows based on the id in first column and adding the values while merging:

```
Class       Sample_1        Sample_2        Sample_3
A           0               0               0
Z           0.25            0               0.75
A|B|C       0.4614726027    2.2609160959    0.2776113014
A|B|C|D|E   0               0.2             0.8
A|B|C|D     0.6390423573    0.5128913443    0.8480662983
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that GNU datamash excels at:

```
$ datamash -H groupby 1 sum 2-4 < file.tsv | column -t
GroupBy(Class)  sum(Sample_1)  sum(Sample_2)  sum(Sample_3)
A               0              0              0
Z               0.25           0              0.75
A|B|C           0.4614726027   2.2609160959   0.2776113014
A|B|C|D|E       0              0.2            0.8
A|B|C|D         0.6390423573   0.5128913443   0.8480662983
```

---

Alternatively, using a 2D array in GNU awk (although note that the order of array traversal is not guaranteed - so the output lines are not necessarily in the same order as the input):

```
$ gawk '
    BEGIN{getline; print} 
    {for(i=2;i<=4;i++) a[$1][i] += $i} 
    END {
      for(k in a){printf k; for(i=2;i<=4;i++) printf "\t%s", a[k][i]; printf "\n"}
    }' file.tsv | column -t
Class      Sample_1  Sample_2  Sample_3
A          0         0         0
A|B|C      0.461473  2.26092   0.277611
A|B|C|D    0.639042  0.512891  0.848066
A|B|C|D|E  0         0.2       0.8
Z          0.25      0         0.75
```

*Note: I added the pipe to `column -t` only for the sake of visual formating*

Comment: sorry, but bash is saying invalid groupby option.

Comment: thank you, gawk command worked.

Comment: could you please explain your gawk code.

Answer (score 0):

Done by below method

```
for i in `awk 'NR>1{if (!seen[$1]++){print $1}}' p.txt`; do awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i{print $0}' p.txt| awk -v i="$i" 'BEGIN{sum=0;hum=0;rum=0}{sum=sum+$2;hum=hum+$3;rum=rum+$4}END {print i,sum,hum,rum}'|awk '{printf "%s%14s%20s%20s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}'; done| sed '1i  Class      Sample_1           Sample_2       Sample_3'
```

output

```
Class      Sample_1           Sample_2       Sample_3
A             0                   0                   0
Z          0.25                   0                0.75
A|B|C      0.461473             2.26092            0.277611
A|B|C|D|E             0                 0.2                 0.8
A|B|C|D      0.639042            0.512891            0.848066
```